# Plugin for "Associate, disassociate" entities no longer works in CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm going to a conversion process from 2011 to 2013 and i have a plugin that is not firing anymore. It's on associate, disassociate of some custom entities and looks like that is not possible anymore.

Does someone manage to solve the problem?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a couple of days of swearing i discovered that based one the view the internal names that are retrieved from the plugin are different. What i mean is that the associated entity name, and the guids are changing based on the grid view you are executing the delete and the add from. This was causing me a bad headache because you need to managed all the cases. Very annoying bust is still possible to make it work. I will write a proper article if i will find the time :)

Comment: did you ever write the article?

Comment: I never had the time. Sorry about that, just be aware that when you use associate/disassociate depending on where you are, the relationship first and second guid are not always written in the same field.